# Error in configuring Mysql database in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have configured for the MySql database in grails by installing MySql in my system and placed its driver in **X/lib** directory(where X is my app name). I have changed the `DataSource.groovy` to conflict the changes. But when i run my app using the command `grails run-app` i'm getting an error as

```
 ERROR spring.BeanBuilder  - WARNING: Your cache provider is set to 'com.opensymphony.oscache.hibernate.OSCacheProvider' in DataSource.groovy, however the class for this provider cannot be found.
```

And Grails started to use its built in database..

How to get rid of this error?

`DataSource.groovy` Code is:

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "grails"
password = "server"
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = true
cache.provider_class =
'com.opensymphony.oscache.hibernate.OSCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
dataSource {
// one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
dbCreate = "create-drop"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack_dev?autoreconnect=true"
}
}
test {
dataSource {
dbCreate = "update"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack_dev?autoreconnect=true"
}
}
production {
dataSource {
dbCreate = "update"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/racetrack_dev?autoreconnect=true"
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your DataSource.groovy file and the excpetion stacktrace?

Comment: You should add the connector to BuildConfig.groovy to `dependencies` section like this: `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'`; also, could you post your DataSource.groovy?

Comment: have you changed the `grails-app/conf/Datasources.groovy` file so that the `url` field points to mysql?

Comment: ya i have did, and added the `DataSource.groovy` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of grails are you using to create that DataSource.groovy file?

Grails 1.3.7 has the hibernate block as:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

Which I think would explain your error message?  (as you have set it up to use the old `OSCacheProvider`

---

***Edit***

These are the steps I just tried, and it all worked as expected:

1. Make a new database (I called mine `ants`)
2. Create the grails app

   ```
   grails create-app ants
   cd ants
   ```
3. Edit the `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` file, and uncomment the lines:

   ```
   mavenCentral()
   ```

   and

   ```
   runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
   ```
4. Edit the file `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy`.

   Change the dataSource block to:

   ```
   dataSource {
       pooled = true
       driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       username = ""
       password = ""
   }
   ```

   And the url (in each of the environments) to

   ```
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ants?autoreconnect=true"
   ```
5. Create a domain class:

   ```
   grails create-domain-class ants.Runners
   ```
6. Run the app

   ```
   grails run-app
   ```

Then, when you inspect the DB, you will have a `runners` table

I am guessing that you are inspecting the wrong database (you have a dev, test, and main db set up, one for each environment)

Comment: No i'm using Grails 1.3.7 but i'm using the book that focus on Grails 1.2. This works, but after running the app using `grails run-app` and then checking MySql table, i see there is no tables have been created yet in it.

Comment: Have you created Domain objects?

Comment: Ya i have already created Domain objects such as `race,runners` etc. My doubt is after changing the database `url` to MySql. Whether I need to create new domain objects to be stored in Mysql? Or the old created one will be replicated in MySql? Because my author says that already created domain objects will get into MySql table(the table have already created!) when we run through `grails run-app`. Is it so?

Comment: restarting the app is equal to running it again using grails run-app? I'm I correct? Or restart needs some other command's?

Comment: Stop it running, then run `grails run-app`

Comment: It doesn't working! Even i tired to create a Race list in my browser and when I see my MySql table then it is showing empty :(

Comment: I just tried it, and it works fine...  the steps I took are above

Comment: Sorry, when i run it, its showing unresolved dependency for MySql Connector. Even though i have placed the driver into grails/lib directory and uncommented the line in `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: Forgot, you need to uncomment `mavenCentral()` in `BuildConfig.groovy`. Don't copy the jar file into `lib`.  I've updated instructions

Comment: @Ant's let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1500/discussion-between-tim-yates-and-anto-aravinth)